# Insert multiple records in databse from single form

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have the following problem:
When I am trying to insert multiple records into a database from a form, only one record gets inserted.

Here is a var_dump of my $_POST variables being submitted

```
array (size=4)
  'date' => string '08-20-2014' (length=10)
  'point_value' => string '987' (length=3)
  'location' => string '46' (length=2)
  'email' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'thisemail@gmail.com' (length=18)
      1 => string 'test@email.com' (length=14)
```

and my php script for inserting the data to the database (None of the validation and such is shown but I do have it in the script)

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$points = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['point_value']);
$date = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['date']);
$loc = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['location']);

$count = count($email);
echo $count;
if ($count == '1'){
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO checkin (checkin_id, date, points, user, location) " . 
            "VALUES (NULL, '".$date."', '".$points."', '".$email."', '".$loc."')";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql1);
}
else {
    $i = 0; $i < count($email); ++$i;
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO checkin (checkin_id, date, points, user, location) " . 
            "VALUES (NULL, '".$date."', '".$points."', '". $mysqli->real_escape_string($email[$i])."', '".$loc."')";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql1);
};
```

I know there is a way to handle inserting multiple records into a database but I need the script to handle whether the user needs to insert only one record or multiple records.

Comment: What you need is to plug your gaping wide open [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities before you start worrying about such things as inserting more/fewer records.

Comment: Where is the `for` statement?

Comment: This should be a for loop: $i = 0; $i < count($email); ++$i;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ought to work:

```
$count = count($email);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO checkin (checkin_id, date, points, user, location) 
    VALUES (NULL, '".$date."', '".$points."', '".$email[$i]."', '".$loc."')";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql1);
};
```